# screens goes up when soft keyboard came in front in And

Tags: android

I have a question that, I want to take our Activity screen up when a softskeyboard came, in my app on Android Phone. I have used *android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"* property in Android Manifest but nothing changed, problem remains same. Please suggest me for the right solution.

Thanks in advance.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/logo" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_height="78dp"></ImageView>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/login_box_bg"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="180dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:id="@+id/ed_Login_Email"
            android:background="@drawable/login_input_bg" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_width="290dip" android:layout_height="40dip" android:hint="Email:" android:paddingLeft="10dp">
        </EditText>
        <EditText android:background="@drawable/login_input_bg" android:layout_width="290dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/ed_Login_Pwd"
            android:inputType="textPassword" android:layout_marginTop="70dip" android:layout_height="40dip" android:hint="Password:" android:paddingLeft="10dip">
        </EditText>
        <Button android:background="@drawable/login_btn_bg" android:id="@+id/btn_Login_Login"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" android:text="LOG IN"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"></Button>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tv_Login_ForgotPwd" android:text="Forgot your password?" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" android:clickable="true"></TextView>
    </FrameLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can u please share xml layout?

Comment: make sure you set minimum api level to 4.

Comment: are you using scroll view in your layout?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point in using both of those settings, AFAIK you have to pick one of them only. Otherwise the system'll try to guess how it should behave, which seems quite unreliable.

I guess you need `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. That'll resize the contents of the screen completely, based on the free space left after the keyboard is displayed.